# Expression Engine: OpenID support?

Tags: openid, expressionengine

Is there a way to use OpenID with EE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [EE Open ID](http://eeopenid.com/).  There is currently not a supported way of using this, but [this thread](http://expressionengine.com/forums/viewthread/24441/) suggests that the devs are aware of the desire in the community.

Comment: This project has been scrapped by the developer.  This would have worked, but they have deleted the download links.

Answer (score 0):

There's now SocialEE: a supported module for RPX within EE. That means you get Facebook Connect, OpenID, the whole shebang.

http://www.shotwellcompany.com/addons/socialee